# Plural of retail

Tags: grammar, nouns

I would like to know what is the plural of retail. Is it ok to just write it as "retails"? It doesn't feel right.

If there isn't a word for the plural of "retail", kindly explain why.

Comment: Can **retail** be used as a _count noun_? What is **one retail**?

Comment: _retail_ is a mass noun.

Comment: The taxidermist re-attached six heads, then did three ...

Comment: Edward, please give an example of a sentence where you want plural "retail", because I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1):

A word for a singular retail store is 'retailer', and plural is 'retailers'.

Comment: To me, *retailer* means the **person** doing the retail, not exactly the shop.

Comment: @marcellothearcane [these](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retailer) [dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retailer) say it also means the business itself.